# Selecting non-alpha chars with QTextCursor

Tags: qt

I'm trying to add syntax completion to a QTextEdit base editor and I'd like to support non-alpha characters to trigger the QCompleter popup. I'm using QTextCursor::select to get the current word but it is always filtering out non-alpha characters. Is there an option I need to use for this ?

Here's the code I use to get the text:

```
QTextCursor tc = textCursor();
tc.select(QTextCursor::WordUnderCursor);
QString t = tc.selectedText();
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Words actually do not contain alpha characters. To select the last input character:

```
QTextCursor tc = textCursor();
tc.movePosition ( QTextCursor::Left, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
QChar lastChar = tc.selectedText().at(0);
if (!lastChar.isLetterOrNumber())
{
do something;
}
```

Replace the isLetterOrNumber() with whatever characters you might check for.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. This code nugget seems to do what I was looking for:

[QString VcsBase::Internal::OutputWindowPlainTextEdit::identifierUnderCursor](http://www.naepl.in/qt/d5/d13/vcsbaseoutputwindow_8cpp_source.html#l00136)